# Method name interchange - public abstract or abstract public

Tags: java

I recently came across the following methods. I tried googling and did an example to see the difference by defining the methods as follows; both seems to be the same. But, i need to know if it's really the same ?

```
public abstract void methodName();
abstract public void methodName();
```

Note:  `public` and `abstract`has been interchanged in the above 2 methods.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731240/what-is-a-reasonable-order-of-java-modifiers-abstract-final-public-static-e

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the same. Don't worry. Two similar declarations of `abstract` method.

Comment: Thank you, i was a bit confused.

Answer (score 25):

There is no difference as far as functionality is concerned but, regardless of whichever you choose, it's best to stay consistent.

That being said, I've almost never seen the `abstract public` used before. So, from a coding standards point of view, `public abstract` is probably going to be more easily recognized by more people.

Answer (score 4):

both are modifiers , you can use in any order

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract void methodName();
abstract public void methodName();
```

These two methods are same similar example is

```
public static void main(String args[]);
static public void main(String args[]);
```

thus above two are same.It is just our wish how we want to write.

Answer (score 2):

Both code is same and compiler will convert it to same byte code if you decompile the code. However it is general practice (not rule of thumb) to begin code with access specifier rather than other keywords.

```
public abstract void methodName();
abstract public void methodName();
```

compiler converts both methods to below code

```
public abstract void methodName();
```

Answer (score 2):

The book "The Java Language Specification, Third Edition" by James Gosling et. al. states in Section 8.4.3 "Method Modifiers" (page 214): "If two or more method modifiers appear in a method declaration, it is customary, although not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for MethodModifier."

The production is:

MethodModifier: one of:
Annotation public protected private abstract static final synchronized native strictfp.

Thus: Yes, formally, the sequence does not matter, but the Java inventors themselves would prefer "public abstract".