# Make Eclipse encourage a certain keyword order

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to try and maintain a certain keyword order ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731240/what-is-a-reasonable-order-of-java-modifiers-abstract-final-public-static-e)). Does Eclipse have an option or a plugin that would make warnings when the order is not maintained? Bonus points, if I can:

- auto-refactor such instances
- issue custom warnings based on a regex(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Eclipse plugin for Checkstyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) can leverage the [ModifierOrder](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html#ModifierOrder) check to warn about incorrect keywords ordering.