# Is public static in any way more meaningful than static public (or vice verse)?

Tags: java

Is `public static` in any way more meaningful than `static public` (or vice verse)?

I've noticed some IDEs offer `public static`, others `static public`...

Comment: No that is only a programming style question (I myself prefer "public static").

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a reasonable order of Java modifiers (abstract, final, public, static, etc.)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731240/what-is-a-reasonable-order-of-java-modifiers-abstract-final-public-static-e)

Comment: It does not matter, but it is good to be consistent. You can use one way for some methods/fields and the other way for others, but it will be more readable if you stick to one way through the entirety of your code.

Answer (score 4):

The Java coding standard, from Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) uses the `public static` format.

Personally, I find it a lot easier to first see something is public and then that it's static, than the other way around. The Java compiler doesn't mind either way, of course, but specifying scope first does feel like it makes your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

These are equivalent. In general, the order of the modifiers in a declaration is not significant. A common convention I have encountered so far is to write `public static`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be argued either way. I'd say you'd want to put "static" first to make your function easier to tell from all other "public" functions that are not static. It follows from "put the distinguishing elements first".