# what does this mean: 'private' modifier out of order with the JLS suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, field, warnings

I first got this warning before adding 'final' to the myItem declaration:

> Private field 'myItem' could be made final; it is only initialized in
>   the declaration or constructor.

```
private Item myItem;
```

After adding final this is the warning i get:

> 'private' modifier out of order with the JLS suggestions.

```
final private Item myItem;
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this? 
I've done some research but can't seem to find anything to solve this problem.

Answer (score 32):

For the first, it's just good practice to make things `final` if they definitely don't change during their lifetime. This helps for reasoning about the mutability of your objects.

For the second warning you're looking for [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html) sections 8.1.1, 8.3.1 and 8.4.1.

`public` or `private` should come before `static`, which should come before `final`.

Answer (score 12):

The usual order is for `private` to come before `final`, like this:

```
private final Item myItem;
```

The code will still compile and behave the same if the modifiers are in a different order, but people who are used to the standard order suggested by the JLS will think your code looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this warning is the order of different type of modifier, please check [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16732059/2000468).

For this case, just put the access modifier before the final.