# Private Final vs Final Private

Tags: java, android

Did a few searched on the inter-webs and could not find an easy answer for this.  My problem set is using Java within the Android Framework, but I believe this is just standard Java behavior as well.  I understand the definitions of `final` and `private`, both used for variable access and modifiers.  I was following some code and tutorials when the instructions asked me to initialize a variable as a `final private` variable.  Not having seen this before, I instead made a `private final` variable.  Later on, the code asked me to initialize the variable in a constructor, which obviously fails against a `private final` variable as it is immutable.  HOWEVER, it did not fail when I changed the variable to a `final private`... which made me interested.  Does anyone have ideas why this is the case?

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: You can assign final undeclared fields within the constructor. Please show an example

Comment: `final private` and `private final` are the **same thing**. The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Java Language Specification, section [8.3.1. Field Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1), says:

> ```
> FieldModifier:
>   (one of)
>   Annotation public protected private
>   static final transient volatile
> ```
>
> If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field declaration, it is **customary**, though **not required**, that they appear in the **order consistent with that shown above** in the production for FieldModifier.

Which means that `private final` is the *preferred* style, but it's exactly the same as `final private`.

Comment: Honestly, this is what I thought was always the case.  I am using IntelliJ/Android Studio, and for some reason the interpreter yelled prior to me actually compiling it stating that I couldn't attempt what I was trying to do.  For some reason it's not saying that anymore, so I honestly have no idea what happened, but regardless, I do appreciate the clarity in case anyone else has this same issue!

Comment: @ShoeShiner most static analyzers, style checkers etc. mark deviations from the order specified in the JLS as issues - perhaps you saw one of these hints?

Answer (score 2):

> Later on, the code asked me to initialize the variable in a
>   constructor, which obviously fails against a private final variable as
>   it is immutable.

Members marked as `final` can be initialized in constructor. You can either create a prameterized constructor which accepts values from outside of class or simply initialize those members directly with declaration. If you choose later and the data type is primitive, then mark those members as `static` since they are going to remain same for all instances of class.

> HOWEVER, it did not fail when I changed the variable to a final
>   private... which made me interested

This won't be possible since `private final` and `final private` and are virtually the same thing and won't make any difference. However former is considered as good practice. You can follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731240/what-is-a-reasonable-order-of-java-modifiers-abstract-final-public-static-e) for more details regarding ordering.

Comment: I disagree on `static` part of answer. You can e.g. declare `final List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>()` which prevents the field from every referencing a different list, but the list itself is not immutable, so each instance can have different lists with different content, and hence `static` is not correct. Down-vote until that part of answer is removed, since it is misleading.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for highlighting. Updated my answer. I missed this point

Answer (score 2):

As an example, here are a couple cases of things that are ok and not ok with `final`. There is no difference between `private final` and `final private`. To add to what @Sagar said, you can initialize the variables inline, or in the constructor, but not both.

```
public class TestClass {

    private final String i1;
    final private String i2;
    private final String i3 = "test"; // ok
    private final String i4; // not ok, never initialized

    TestClass() {
        i1 = "test1"; // ok
        i2 = "test2"; // ok
        i3 = "test3"; // not ok, overrides already set value
    }

    void mod() {
        i1 = "test0"; // not ok, can't edit final i1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`private final` and `final private` has no difference. For access modifiers the order does not matter. So both of them will have similar behavior.

Try this:

```
public class Test {

    private final String privateFinal;
    final private String finalPrivate;

    public Test() {
        privateFinal = "Private Final";
        finalPrivate = "Final Private";
    }
}
```

The above code compiles absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0):

they're the same thing.
private final > final private