# What is the difference between these two class headers?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, abstraction

I've been researching abstract classes and wondering what the difference between these two headers for an abstract class are? I've seen both syntaxes in difference place and am wondering what is the correct way to write an abstract class header.

```
abstract public class AbstractClass
```

or

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
```

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731240/what-is-a-reasonable-order-of-java-modifiers-abstract-final-public-static-e/16732059#16732059

Comment: There is no semantic difference.

The spec recommends an order:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299067/modifier-keyword-order-in-java

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708181/method-name-interchange-public-abstract-or-abstract-public